# How to download multiple file in angular 2

Tags: angular

This is code to download file in angular 2. I want to download pdf, txt, docx, excel file with this code. I used file saver so can we download diffrent files on click of button.

```
public downloadCSVFile()
   {
      this.downloadPdf().subscribe(
      (res) => 
         { 
            //console.log(res);   
            saveAs(res,'Frontend.xlsx')
         }
      );
   }

   public downloadPdf(): any 
   {
      let urls='assets/Files/Frontend.xlsx'
      let headers = new Headers();
      //headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
      return this.http.get(urls, { headers: headers,responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
         (res) => {
            return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
         })
   }
```

This is my html code So how to download diffrent file. As file name displayed in table so i want that corrosponding file to be downloaded.

```
<tr *ngFor ="let mydrive of providerMyDrive">
         <td>{{ mydrive.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ mydrive.filetype }}</td>
         <td>{{ mydrive.size }}</td>
         <td>{{ mydrive.uploaddate }}</td>
         <td><input type="button" (click)="downloadCSVFile()" value="Download"></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a link and click it:

```
this.storageService.downloadFile(path).subscribe(
      res => {
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.blob());
        link.download = path;

        link.click();
      }, error => this.globalService.errorSubject.next(error)
    );
```